# Calling function with optional type in Swift

Tags: swift, option-type

Let's say I have the following:

```
var didConnectObserver: NSObjectProtocol?

didConnectObserver = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(
    MyKey, object: nil, queue: nil, usingBlock: { (note) -> Void in
    ...
})
```

At some point I unregister:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(didConnectObserver)
```

This doesn't work, though, because `didConnectObserver` is an optional. Is there a more compact way to write this than:

```
if let obs = didConnectObserver {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(obs)
}
```

that still does the right thing if `didConnectObserver` is `nil`?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I was thinking about this the other day though. I think it's a legitimate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still getting the hang of `map` with Optionals, but I believe this will work:

```
_ = didConnectObserver.map(NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver)
```

If `didConnectObserver` is `nil`, the result of this is `nil`, otherwise it executes the function with `didConnectObserver!`.  The `_ =` is necessary to suppress a warning `Result of call to 'map' is unused`.

Here's what autocomplete shows when you type `didConnectObserver.map`:

### [image]

Here is another example of the same concept:

```
func add5(i: Int) {
    print("add 5 called")
    print(i + 5)
}

let a: Int? = 10

_ = a.map(add5)
```

If `a` is `nil`, then `add5` is not called.  If `a` is `Optional(10)`, then `add5` is called and `15` is printed.

It works just like:

```
if a != nil {
    add5(a!)
}
```

Comment: i think map needs to be called on a sequence type (like an array for example),  and also i think the you would need to use ?  .. ie didConnectObserver?.map { ... }

Comment: You can call map on a single Optional.  Take a look at the example which works.

Comment: It would be nice if Swift would make Optional conform to `CollectionType` (like Scala does), or at least to `SequenceType`, so it would have `forEach` and `filter`. The `map` function works here but `forEach` would make more sense if it were available.

Comment: Awesome. Didn't know you can call `map` on it. That would be very similar to a Functor.